# how to get more items if page doesn't have scroll

Tags: angularjs

I make calls for more items by infinite scrolling, but it fails if the initially loaded items don't fill the screen, I mean in this situation:

```
document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.clientHeight
```

the directive works fine if the page has scroll-bar:

```
app.directive('infinitescroll', function ($rootScope, $http, $window) {
  return function ($scope, $element) {

    angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function() {
      // 100 pixels gap at the bottom of page for triggering the fetcher 
      clientHeight = html.scrollHeight - 100; 
      scrollHeight = html.scrollTop + document.querySelector('body').clientHeight;
      if (clientHeight <= scrollHeight) {
        fetcher ();
      }
    }); 

    function fetcher () {
      //get the Id of last item >> lastId
      $http.get(app.apiBaseUrl + '/items/' + lastId).then(function (response) {
         // now pushing new items to $scope
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I can check in controller if

```
document.body.scrollHeight >= document.body.clientHeight
```

otherwise call for more items, but it's a bad practice to check scrollheight in controller, kindly please tell me how to check it in the above directive.

Comment: The question is how to get from where ? from backend ? why you dont doing it in fetcher function ?

Comment: @narek-mamikonyan thanks. I explained more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to suggest create Service for fetcher, and inject it in directive. 
Your fetcher can have a function into which you can pass id and it will do request to backend and will return the response, then you can inject it to your directive,
about directive: You can make a directive with restriction A and set as body attribute like this:

```
<body infinitescroll>
```

In this way you will have in directive `element` which already wrapped in jQuery and you do not need to do `document.querySelector('body')` 
so after your calculation you can fetch your data from server and send it to those controller which you need through `$emit` or `$boradcast`

Comment: thank you @narek-mamikonyan. about the body, I can't use it on body because I need this directive in some pages and not for the rest, and also getting with querySelector let's me choose if the scrolling element is the body tag or the html tag(for Firefox), I didn't put it in code for readability.